# Devise equivalent in Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

I need a authentication solution like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for an app that I am writing using Play Framework. I'd appreciate any pointers towards a full fledged solution or work in progress that I can build upon.

Comment: What is so nice at Devise? It's easier to answer your questions if you describe what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silhouette or Play-Authenticate, as of Play 2.4

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an complete out of box existing solution but Play includes standard mecanisms of Authentication and Authorization. Based upon [roles and checks](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/secure). Here is the [YABE example](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/guide8).

There are also some modules available from the community, if you really want to build your own stuff, you can use those as a start : http://www.playframework.org/modules. Check out for "auth", there are some results.

But still, I think that perhaps you are looking at the problem from the wrong way. By switching technology, you have to accept to do things differently and not always seek to do as you would do in another language. Play! has it way of thinking, it's own conception mode and trying to adapt existing patterns from other technologies might not be as glorious as expected.

Comment: I have never used RoR. Just read about Devise and found that it fit my requirements. Didn't want to learn Ruby coming from a Java background. Thank you for the pointers, will look into it.